# SwiftUI flashing animation to black rather than previous colour

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have a task running in my view model and when it is complete I want the background colour to flash red for a few seconds before staying red. I can get this working fairly well using the playground code below.

But the issue is I want the flashing to be [red, black, red, black, red] not [orange, red, orange, red, orange, red]. I feel like this should be fairly easy (it was in UIKit!) but I can't come up with a good way to do it that doesn't involve me adding something complicated and bug prone like having something in my view model that switches the colour back and forth quickly.

Presumeably something using AnimatableModifier is the way to go, but given my failure to take example code and get it to do anything resembling what I want I clearly don't understand how it works...

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   enum TaskState {
      case started
      case nearlyFinished
      case finished
   }

   private var timer: Timer?
   private var timerTwo: Timer?
   @Published var myTaskState: TaskState

   init() {
      myTaskState = .started
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.myTaskState = .nearlyFinished})
      self.timerTwo = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4.0, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.myTaskState = .finished})
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

   var body: some View {
      ZStack {
         myColor
         Text("Test").foregroundColor(.white)
      }
   }

   private var myColor: some View {
      var repeatingAnimation: Animation {
         Animation
            .linear(duration: 0.5)
            .repeatCount(9, autoreverses: true)
      }

      switch viewModel.myTaskState {
         case .started: return Color.black.animation(.linear(duration: 0.0))
         case .nearlyFinished: return Color.orange.animation(.linear(duration: 0.0))
         case .finished: return Color.red.animation(repeatingAnimation)
      }

   }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Thanks to [this video](https://youtu.be/A4Byyls7zww) for the explaining it in a way that made sense to me.

Perhaps there is a simpler way, but I created an AnimatableModifier that adjusts its opacity between transparent and an input colour according to a sine wave with an input number of peaks and then put it in front of the background colour.

I had to add the .onReceive and .withAnimation because if I you just have it as in the commented out lines below it never goes fully black. Perhaps because some other properties are also being animated?

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   enum TaskState {
      case started
      case nearlyFinished
      case finished
   }

   private var timer: Timer?
   private var timerTwo: Timer?
   @Published var myTaskState: TaskState

   init() {
      myTaskState = .started
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.myTaskState = .nearlyFinished})
      self.timerTwo = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4.0, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.myTaskState = .finished})
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
   @State private var flashing = false

   var body: some View {
      ZStack {
         myColor
         Color.clear
            //.modifier(AnimatableFlasher(flashColor: .black, flashes: 10, pct: viewModel.myTaskState == .finished ? 1.0 : 0.0))
            //.animation(.linear(duration: 5.0))
            .modifier(AnimatableFlasher(flashColor: .black, flashes: 10, pct: self.flashing ? 1.0 : 0.0))
            .onReceive(viewModel.$myTaskState, perform: { myTaskState in
               withAnimation(.linear(duration: 5.0)) {
                  self.flashing = myTaskState == .finished
               }
            })

         Text("Test").foregroundColor(.white)

      }
   }

   struct AnimatableFlasher: AnimatableModifier {
      let flashColor: UIColor
      let flashes: Int
      var pct: CGFloat = 0

      var animatableData: CGFloat {
         get { pct }
         set { pct = newValue }
      }

      func body(content: Content) -> some View {
         let opacity = oscillateOpacity(flashes: flashes, pct: pct)
         return Color(flashColor).opacity(opacity)
      }

      func oscillateOpacity(flashes: Int, pct: CGFloat) -> Double {
         let reducedPct = pct - floor(pct)
         return (1.0 - cos(Double(reducedPct)*Double(flashes)*Double.pi*2)) / 2.0
      }
   }

   private var myColor: some View {
      switch viewModel.myTaskState {
      case .started: return Color(.black)
      case .nearlyFinished: return Color(.orange)
      case .finished: return Color(.red)
      }

   }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel()))
```